# Regex Syntax Validator

Tags: regex, syntax, highlighting, validation

Does anybody know any tool for validating the syntax of an Regular Expression? I dont want to validate if it matches or not with some text but I want to see if there are syntax errors in the regex (missing parenthisis etc).

Also, what about syntax highlighting? It would be a great help when writing complex regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used RegexBuddy for more than half a year. Highly recommended.

Comment: RegexBuddy looks really good. I will try it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://regexpal.com/ has a form of syntax highlighting. As for validating, that would depend on which engine you are working with, since different engines support different syntaxes. It would be impossible to validate something without knowing exactly which syntax the engine you are targeting supports.

Answer (score 0):

I like rubular.com